# PrintElem dont work in the newest windows update

Tags: javascript, css

I have a script that's supposed to print a specific div when clicking on a link, it worked perfect until the newest Windows update came, i've been using Google Chrome with kiosk mode, for silent printing.
I've tried de disable kiosk mode, but still nothing happens, when i click on the link, it just refresh the page.

The link looks like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="PrintElem('.mydiv5')" />
```

And then my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function PrintElem(elem)
        {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
        {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body><p style="font-family:arial">');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</p></body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

And finally, the last bit, the div i'm printing

```
<div class="mydiv5" style="display:none;">
Test
</div>
```

What can i do to make everything work again, it happened exactly the same day after my pc updated.

If i mark something on a website and click CTRL + P, it prints just fine.

Hope you can help.

Comment: do you get any developer tools console errors?

Comment: windows update has made a change to how chrome works? *shakes fist at Microsoft*

Comment: I cant see what the problem should be, if it's not in the windows update, it works on a windows 7 installation. So im 99% sure that it's something about the update.
As far as i can see i dont get any console errors.